# how to get data of ntfs to linux?

Tags: centos

I have dual boot of Windows 2003 server and Cent-OS 6.X on my PC. I have files in windows environment, can I get those files using any utility to my Linux environment with out using any external drives?

Comment: Use the ntfs-3g.

Comment: To expand on Alko's comment, here's a link that explains the whole process - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-fedora-enable-ntfs3g-support/

Answer (score 0):

For mounting `NTFS` you have to enable the modules on kernel and compile it after rebooting you can mount it,its a lengthy process. or you can install a packages ntfs-3g follow [this](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS) guide for complete tutorial on it.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Linux distributions come with preconfigured desktop environments (and ntfs-3g pre-installed) that allow you to simply click on the windows/ntfs drive in your normal file manager to mount it and to view/modify its contents.

Keep in mind that dual booting when used with windows readyboost or hibernation might cause serious problems (e.g. dataloss or filesystem corruption).

Answer (score -1):

You should mount ntfs partition of windows like "sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/Y" where X is your ntfs partition number and Y is mount folder.To learn X number issue "sudo fdisk -l".Then you can access your files via /mnt/Y .